# Where does the BF1942 Patcher search for the Game?

Tags: technical-issues, battlefield-1942

My problem is that I have the Battlefield 1942 file on my desktop but the patcher can not find the file. So I need to know where the patcher searches for the gamefile. I have Windows XP.